# Odd Javascript behavior - porting to WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm currently making my first effort into porting a webpage to Wordpress, so forgive my inexperience on the subject.

In my page, I have the following code:

```
function workLoad() {

  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

  $('.thumb-unit').click(function() {

    var $this = $(this),
        newTitle = $this.find('strong').text(),
        newFolder = $this.data('folder'),
        spinner = 'Loading...',
        newHTML = 'work/'+ newFolder +'.html';
    $('.project-load').html(spinner).load(newHTML);
    $('.project-title').text(newTitle);


  });

}
```

In the past, this has worked fine hosted both locally and on Github. However, running my wordpress build locally through MAMP gives me the following error:

```
jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4 GET http://localhost/work/proj-1.html?_=1485348127113 404 (Not Found)
```

The URL should be fine, except for the part where it adds the ?_=(number). I'm not familiar with this behavior or what causes it. I tried changing work/ to /work/, since the dir is in the root folder, but that didn't solve it. I also have tried changing the variable to

`newHTML = '< ?php bloginfo('template_directory')' + '/work/'+ newFolder +'.html';`*without the space after the opening bracket* but to no avail. I also tried putting that bit in its own var, but it keeps adding `?_=1485348127113` to the URL of the html file I want to load, resulting in a 404 error.

What causes this? Thanks in advance for any advice you could share.

Answer (score 0):

This timestamp is added for You to obtain the latest version of the file using ajax load.
If You want to disable this behaviour, You should set

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache: true
});
```

This will enable caching and Your request would not contain the `?_=1485348127113` part anymore. This parameter should not cause the 404 not found error. Please check your path.

Comment: Thanks for your insight @Sebastian Krysiak. The path should be correct, but I will double check when I get home.  Chrome developer tools lists the entire filename including the timestamp, so I'm guessing there is a conflict somewhere where the timestamp interferes with the script. I'll try your solution and get back to you. Cheers!

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that you were right: the issue was with the folder structure and thus the path of the file. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Max de Ruiter glad i could help : )